# Ant equivalent of Maven profiles?

Tags: maven-2, ant

Is there an Ant equivalent to the 'profile' concept in Maven?

I'd like to be able to specify a different set of targets to build (out of one Ant file) depending on an argument.  So in Maven I can specify a profile and then activate it like so: `mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -Denvironment=test`

So say my build.xml contains:

```
<target name="profile1">...</>
```

and

```
<target name="profile2">...</>
```

How could I specify at compile time which I want to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass arguments to ant when you invoke it

```
ant -DProfile=foo
```

Then `${Profile}` will substitute for `foo`

This is a sucky workaround but it should be able to pass arguments via the command line if that is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can read properties from files using the [`property`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) or [`loadproperties`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) tasks.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to replicate this might do.

Comment: Thx.  I already have properties being injected... this isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I updated the question with more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case: "ant profile1".  The second case is left as an exercise.

Seriously, the list of targets you want to execute is already an argument to ant.  I think you need to make your example a little more explicit.